# Solace Guaranteed Message Publish issue

Tags: solace

We encountered publish Guaranteed Message Publish error, it reports:

```
[ERR] {"message":"Guaranteed Message Window Closed","name":"OperationError","subcode":22,"level":"error","stack":"OperationError: Guaranteed Message Window Closed\n 
    at PublisherFSM.prepareAdMessageAndSend (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:21530:13)\n 
    at MessagePublisher.prepareAdMessageAndSend (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:20866:22)\n 
    at SessionFSM.prepareAndSendMessage (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:26483:49)\n 
    at Session.validateAndSendMessage (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:29161:22)\n 
    at Session.send (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:28463:10)\n
```

Known that is due to client side pended many unacknowledged messages (default window size is 50) https://solace.com/blog/understanding-guaranteed-message-publish-window-sizes-and-acknowledgement/. Per check the log, application side can receive acknowledge notification after it publish to solace more than 1 sec.

So what's the root cause introduced solace server can't acknowledge so many messages at client side? we checked the client application log, and just find below solace related error:

```
at PublisherFSM.process (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:17780:11)
at PublisherFSM.processEvent (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:17841:15)
at State.onEntry (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:2201:17)
at BufferSMFClient.rxDataBuffer (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:33020:10)
at CorrelatedRequest.respRecvdCallback (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:21257:77)
at SessionFSM.handleADCtrlMessage (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:25872:26)

ERROR  solclientjs:  Uncaught exception in {PublisherFSM: PublisherFSM} while processing {PublisherFSMEvent: MessagePublisherFailed}: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextCorrelationTag' of null
    at PublisherFSM.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:17847:49)
    at State.handleOpenFlowResponse (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:21120:22)
    at TcpRawTransport.onData (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:34168:20)
    at SessionFSM.getCorrelationTag (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:25777:28)
    at SessionFSM.handleSMFMessage (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:26116:23)
    at BufferSMFClient._rxSmfCB (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:26352:41)
    at BufferSMFClient._rxDataCB (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:33074:16)
    at State.sendOpenFlow (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:21244:47)
    at State.onEntry (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:21262:14)
    at State.processReactionResult (/home/vcap/deps/0/node_modules/solclientjs/lib/solclientjs-debug.js:9001:18)
```

We used solclientjs 10.2.1, and Solace VMR 9.0.0.17.

We can only restart the client application, but those unacknowledged messages are lost.

Comment: Is PERSISTENT mode better than DIRECT mode when we publish messages to solace topic?

Comment: Whether Persistent mode is better than Direct or not depends on your usecase. Persitent mode or guaranteed messaging should be used for critical messages which you would like to publish even if the consumer is not available. If you were to publish direct messages and there was no one to receive them, they would be lost forever.

Comment: So, if there are one queue subscribed the topic, what's the possible reasons that the direct messages will be lost? queue message store issue, for example, exceed quota?

Comment: In Solace, you can have publishers publishing direct messages to the broker and then being promoted to guaranteed messages if they are subscribed to a queue by a consumer.

If you are attracting a direct message to a queue, it has now been PROMOTED to a guaranteed message with persistence. It will not be lost. 

I recommend checking out https://solace.community/ for any follow-up questions you might have.